# gcc preprocessor typedef name replacement

Tags: c, gcc

Is there a way to get the gcc preprocessor to replace a type with what defined by the typedef, i.e.

something like this:

```
typedef unsigned char Uint8

int main(void)
{
    Uint8 a = 1;
    Uint8 b = 2;
    Uint8 c;

    c = a + b;

    return 0;
}
```

Would get preprocessed into something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char a = 1;
    unsigned char b = 2;
    unsigned char c;

    c = a + b;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to the preprocessor to do this? Let the `typedef` do its job

Comment: try what? You didn't given an example.

Comment: I am want to do a custom parse of the file myself and having the preprocessor do the replacement would make it easier for my custom parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't, because type aliasing is part of compilation stage and not a pre-processing stage. Therefore pre-processor cannot know anything about types by design and cannot perform any operations on those types. Also, you forgot to put `;` at the end of typedef statement.